# Checking which layer edited under specific version?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, versioning

I have approx 100 feature class in SDE database. Out of this someone edited 10 in "test_1" version feature class(assumed). Now i want to know with script or manual which feature class is edited under "test_1" version.

How can I check this?

Comment: Has anyone reconciled and posted test_1? If not, do a version compare with default (or parent). I don't think you need to add all 100 features to your map to see the differences.